# Is there any better option than passport for securing rest api , I want to integrate these api's on android also

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit, laravel-passport

Is there any better option for securing api's other than laravel passport , I want to integrate these api's with android also.

I have tried with passport but in that we have to create user and then authentication and token generation take place. I have only the login api that is read api , users are not getting registered by my api , entry of users are there in the database.I want authenticate them and if authenticated person login then want to generate token. I also want to integrate my api's with android.

Comment: You can generate a unique token and save it to database when user logins. After generating token, you can return it as response and android device will store this token in it's local storage. After that you have send token to every api call and in server end you need token checking mechanism to allow/reject the request.